# How do I holster weapons?

Tags: the-division

I cannot seem to figure this out. It's frustrating, as there is no information in the help file, control settings, or even their guide.

How do you holster weapons? I would like to stop scaring civilians away.

I am playing on Xbox One.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't manually holster weapons. The only time that your weapons are holstered is when you are in a safe area (your base of operations, a safe house, etc.).